# Why does the inclusion of \hyperref cause rendering problems in MWE

Tags: formatting, packages

```
%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %


%\usepackage{hyperref} % if hyperref is included, dvi will not render

\begin{document}

Hi there.

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** This question appears to be concerned with the YAP previewing software. Running `latex` on the MWE (with `hyperref` included), opening the dvi file with YAP and then selecting View -> Render method -> PK does seem to produce an error. The error goes away if one chooses View -> Render method -> dvips instead.

Comment: it would help if you would mention how you are trying to render the dvi (I haven't done it for ages).

Comment: I tried and it renders well on my machine with `xdvi`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher using the kp? default option - not the dvips. I have used MiKTeX for eight years and not had any problem.  It started about three weeks ago; I have reinstalled MiKTeX 21.8 more than six times but the problem persists.

Comment: I have run chkdsk and scannow on my PC showing no issues.

Comment: Try with `\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}`. But basically it is better to use the dvips render method.

Comment: Yes, \usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref} does work both with pk and dvips, but is that just a work-around.  MiKTeX has only recently been doing this - something has changed.

Comment: what is pk here ?

Comment: pk - actually Pk is one of two options for rendering the dvi output; the other being dvips.

Comment: it is not a work-around.  The correct driver for this mode is `hypertex`, for the dvips renderer it is dvips. The wrong driver can work but there is no garanty.

Comment: I've tested the hypertex option in my full working file.  Unfortunately, it then does not render.  Only following a successful render can one change from Kp tp dvips!

Comment: Are pk and kp different things, or is one of them a typo? Could you provide a link to some information about it/them? I've never heard of a dvi viewer or processor called pk or kp (admittedly, I haven't used a dvi viewer for a very long time).

Comment: odd never heard of pk (other than the packed font file format for metatfont fonts)  I thought the miktex dvi previewer was yap? dvips is a program that reads dvi files, can you point to any documentation for the pk program? but you keep alternating beween kp and pk, which is it?

Comment: It is Pk.  If you run my MWE without the line containing \hyperref, it will render and under view, you will see the two options: Kp and dvips - it defaults to Kp.

Comment: If you run with the line \hyperref, it will not render; this used not to be the case.

Comment: Each one of the respondents so far appears to imply they have not used MiKTex for some time.  If that is the case, would I and others benefit by changing to some  other program?

Comment: @keith77777 --- Can you add a screenshot showing where you see the two options 'kp' and 'dvips'? Ideally, please show the whole window.

Comment: %
%--------------------------------------- %
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
%--------------------------------------- %

\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Hi there.

\end{document}

Comment: Sorry, the options only show while the selection key is being pressed.  If you run the code immediately above, one of the output headers is "view".  Under view click on render to see Kp or dvips.

Comment: I have found that using the driver [hypertex] as suggested by Ulrike removes all the problems except when the package bookmark is present.

Comment: I think you are referring to an issue with the YAP previewing software, and have edited your question accordingly. Please feel free to undo the edit if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: @Ian Thompson I thank you for your continued interest and accept your edit.

Comment: @IanThompson I have found that, in ordinary usage, even if rendering is achieved with the Dvips option...  after closing the program and restarting, the program defaults back to Kp and rendering is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use YAP and its pk-Render mode you must load `hyperref` with the option `hypertex`

```
 \usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}
```

You can't use the `bookmark` package with the pk-Renderer as `bookmark` hasn't a suitable driver.

YAP + the dvips render mode should work with both packages (if they use a dvips driver, which they normally do).

You can set the dvips render mode permantly in the options (which you find in the `View` menu:

[image]

Personally while I do have a current miktex and use it I didn't use YAP for ages. I compile with pdflatex to pdf and use a pdf viewer. Or if I use the latex+dvips compilation I compile with ps2pdf to pdf and view again in a pdf viewer.

Comment: Thank you.  It's not that I want to use the Pk option, it is that the output will not render at all, and therefore I cannot even get to selecting the Dvips option.  Only by tricking the program by running my MWE can I get to select Dvips.  Then, if I close the program, the problems recurs.

Comment: I have been using this same setup for more than six years and I am absolutely sure this problem did not materialize until about 4 weeks ago.

Comment: then ask the right question: how to set the default render method. Open yap, go to the menu View -> options -> tab display and switch the default there.

Comment: Problem solved.  So setting the render option in yap.exe to Dvips outside of MiKTeX is a pre-requisite to guaranteeing success in producing dvi output.  I have not seen that said anywhere previously.  Thank you.