# Problem with dvi and PSTricks in Winedt 10.3

Tags: pstricks

I'm trying to compile (TeXify) the following code with Winedt 10.3 and I get the message "The page could not be rendered" in dvi:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-intersect,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(8,8)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,ticksize=0 4pt]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(8,8)[$M$,-90][$Y$,0]
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic}
\pssavepath[linecolor=green]{A}{\psplot{-0.5}{8}{4*(1-1.2^(-3*x+1))}}
\psline[linecolor=red](-2,4)(8,4) \uput[90](7,4){$Y=\dfrac{A}{\alpha+d}$}
\pssavepath[linecolor=blue]{B}{\psplot{-0.5}{8}{2^(-x/2+3)-2}}
\pssavepath[linestyle=none]{C}{\psplot{-0.5}{8}{0}}
\psintersect[name=D, showpoints]{A}{B}\uput[0](D1){$M_3^*,Y^*$}
\psintersect[name=E, showpoints]{A}{C}\uput[-45](E1){$M_c$}
\psdot(4,0)\uput[225](4,0){$M_c^*$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Some suggestion for this? With thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // It may be an issue of the compile settings. At least I have to change them when I compile with Texmaker. // You can also verify by deleting (or commenting out) parts of your code. E.g. start with removing the pspicture environemnt. Next split the code inside into "half", delete one, check and repeat with the other part. Repeat until you homed in onto the problem.

Comment: which dvi viewer do you use? YAP? Then ensure that you are using the dvips render method, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621882/2388

Comment: I have no problem to visualize the .ps file with gsview6.0